# Calculating Power of a Paired T Test

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, self-learning

$ 239$ subjects had their cholesterol measured, and then were put on high-fiber diets. After a month on the high-fiber diet, the cholesterol was measured again. The mean LDL cholesterol level before the experiment was $118.5 $ mg/DL. The mean level after the subjects were on a diet for a month was $113.7$ mg/DL. The sample standard deviation of the amount of cholesterol each patient lost was $ 38.37$ mg/DL.
(a) Test whether or not the high-fiber data significantly reduced the LDL cholesterol level at an α = 0.05 level.

For this one I just used a paired to test. The hypothesis are $ H_0: \mu_d\leq 0$ and $ H_a: \mu_d>0$. We see that $\bar{d}=\bar{x}_{before}-\bar{x}_{after}=118.5-113.7=4.8$. It follows that $t_0=\dfrac{\bar{d}}{\dfrac{s_d}{\sqrt{n}}}=\frac{4.8}{\frac{38.37}{\sqrt{239}}}=1.933\implies 1.933>t_{0.05,238}=1.645$ Thus we reject the null hypothesis $ H_0$

(b) If the true reduction in cholesterol was 10 mg/DL, what is the power of this test?

We assume that $ \mu_d=10$. Since [math] n[/math] is large we can use a normal approximation. Thus it follows that $ \bar{d}=N(\mu_d,\dfrac{\sigma^2_{before}}{239}+\dfrac{\sigma^2_{after}}{239}$. Also we shall assume that $\dfrac{s_d}{\sqrt{239}}$ is approximately $\sqrt{\dfrac{\sigma^2_{before}}{239}+\dfrac{\sigma^2_{after}}{239}}$. Thus Power$$=P(t_0\in R|\mu_d=10)=P(\dfrac{\bar{d}}{\dfrac{38.37}{\sqrt{239}}}>1.645|\mu_d=10)= P(\dfrac{\bar{d}}{\dfrac{38.37}{\sqrt{239}}}-\dfrac{10}{\dfrac{38.37}{\sqrt{239}}}>1.645-{\dfrac{38.37}{\sqrt{239}}}) =P(\dfrac{\bar{d}-10}{\dfrac{38.37}{\sqrt{239}}}>1.62814)=P(Z>1.62814)]= 1-P(Z\leq 1.62814 )=1-.94825=.05175$$.

This is what I get for part b. I think it looks right but im not entirely sure. I'm basing the rejection region off of part (a) that is reject the null hypothesis as long as the T statistic is greater that $ T_{0.05,238}$.

Comment: Is it correct? I mainly want to know for part b.

Comment: If I understand the problem, the standard error of $\bar x$ is estimated to be $38.37/\sqrt{239} = 2.482$ and you want to know if you can detect a difference of 10, which is about 4 standard errors. Intuitively, it seems to me you are very likely to reject. So the power should be near 1. (Power computations are always difficult to think about when the concept is new. Maybe look again with the idea of getting power near 1.)